# Problem with get_post_meta

Tags: post-meta

I am using this code to retrieve post meta:

```
if ( get_post_meta($post->ID,'a',true) == '') {
    echo '<img src="' . get_bloginfo( 'template_url' ) . '/img/img22.jpg" ></img>';
} else {
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'a',true); 
}
```

My first block of if statement is always executing no matter whether the mete box text field is empty or not and else block is not executing in any case. I want to know if there is any flaw in this code or

```
echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'a',true)
```

is not a valid code. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you put `var_dump(get_post_meta($post->ID,'a',true))` before the if, what do you get?

Comment: It's displaying this     string '' (length=0)

Comment: Well there is your answer - the post does not have a meta value with key `a` ;)

Comment: Actually I have a meta value with key a but not figuring out what's getting it not work.

Comment: No, you do not. If you would have it, than this would return it ;) Try `var_dump(get_post_meta($post->ID))` and it will return all the meta values you have.

Comment: Comments are not appropriate for extended discussion. Please any new details by editing the original question and take overly long dialogs to the chat.

Comment: If the below answer did answer your question please accept it.

Answer (score 2):

I was having some issues like yours.  It was because it was on a page template with a query above it.  All I had to do was reset the [query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query).

Answer (score 0):

try this.Hope this will work fine

```
$key_1_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'a', true);
    // check if the custum field has a value
    if($key_1_value != '') {
      echo $key_1_value;
    } else{
      echo '<img src="' . get_bloginfo( 'template_url' ) . '/img/img22.jpg";
    }
```

Comment: sorry it's not working. It's just the same as before.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP empty() function as the condition to check whether meta value is null or not:

```
<?php
    $my_val = get_post_meta($post->ID,'a',true);
    if( empty( $my_val ) ) {
        echo '<img src="' . get_bloginfo( 'template_url' ) . '/img/img22.jpg" ></img>';
    } else {
        echo $my_val; 
    }
?>
```

Comment: sorry it's not working. It's just the same as before.

Comment: can you please var_dump(get_post_meta($post->ID,'a',true)) and send the result here so that i might help.

Comment: This is what is shows "string '' (length=0)"

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<?php if( ( $usermeta  = get_post_meta($post->ID,'a',true)) && !empty($usermeta) ){
                        echo $usermeta; 

                    }else{
                        echo '<img src="' . get_bloginfo( 'template_url' ) . '/img/img22.jpg" ></img>';
                    } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks monirul but I am sorry no change. Still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue and managed to overcome it by replacing this code:

```
(get_post_meta($post->ID,'a',true)
```

with the following:

```
(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'a',true)
```

Hope that will save somebody the trouble of getting stuck.